# How to handle when no search results are found using material-table with React and remote data

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I'm using [material-table](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table) with React using remote data. In cases when no search results are found I'm trying to sort out how to remove the display of the spinner and show the "No records to display". The search executes the web service call after each keystroke in the search field. I think what I'm after is to set a timeOut to stop the spinner, but I'm sure where to add this in the code below and am a bit confused in the syntax.

```
render() {
    return (
        <MaterialTable
            icons={tableIcons}
            title="Remote Data Preview"
            columns={[
                { title: 'Publication ID', field: 'publicationId' },
                { title: 'PMID', field: 'pmid' },
                { title: 'First author', field: 'firstAuthor' },
                { title: 'Publication', field: 'title' },
                { title: 'Journal', field: 'journal' },
                { title: 'Status', field: 'status' },
            ]}
            data={query =>
                new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    let url = GET_PUBLICATIONS_URL

                    if (query.search) {
                        url += query.search + '?pmid=true'

                        fetch(url)
                            .then(response => response.json())
                            .then(result => {
                                resolve({
                                    data: [result],
                                    page: 0,
                                    totalCount: 1,
                                })
                            }).catch(error => {
                            })
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("** No PMID added...")
                        url += '?size=' + query.pageSize
                        url += '&page=' + (query.page)

                        fetch(url)
                            .then(response => response.json())
                            .then(result => {
                                resolve({
                                    data: result._embedded.publications,
                                    page: result.page.number,
                                    totalCount: result.page.totalElements,
                                })
                                console.log("** Data: ", result._embedded.publications);
                            }).catch(error => {
                                 setTimeout(resolve, 1000)
                                 return Promise.reject(error);
                            })
                    }
                })
            }
            options={{
                search: true
            }}
        />
    )
}
```

When no search results are returned using the above code the console shows:

Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0
material-table.js:249 
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'totalCount' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

What if we consider: extract Fetching Data from the `data` property for the table to a standard method, invoke it at the `componentDidMount` and remove the *promise* since it's not needed there, let's see if that would solve the problem:

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.getTableData();
}

getTableData = query => {
    let url = GET_PUBLICATIONS_URL;
    if (query.search) {
      url += query.search + '?pmid=true';

      fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
          this.setState({
            tableData: {
              data: [result],
              page: 0,
              totalCount: 1,
            }
          })
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.setState({
            error: {
              id: 2,
              error: error.message
            }
          })
        })
    } else {
      url += '?size=' + query.pageSize;
      url += '&page=' + (query.page);
      fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
          this.setState({
            tableData: result._embedded.publications,
            page: result.page.number,
            totalCount: result.page.totalElements,
          })
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.setState({
            error: {
              id: 2,
              error: error.message
            }
          })
        })
    }
}

render() {
  const { state: { tableData } } = this;

  return (
    <MaterialTable
      icons={tableIcons}
      title="Remote Data Preview"
      columns={[
          { title: 'Publication ID', field: 'publicationId' },
          { title: 'PMID', field: 'pmid' },
          { title: 'First author', field: 'firstAuthor' },
          { title: 'Publication', field: 'title' },
          { title: 'Journal', field: 'journal' },
          { title: 'Status', field: 'status' },
      ]}
      data={tableData.data}
      options={{search: true}}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I ran into some issues with the above I'll need to sort out, but do prefer the cleaner approach. 

One thing I've been able to sort out in the interirm is adding:
`setTimeout(() => {
                            resolve({
                                data: [],
                                page: 0,
                                totalCount: 0,
                            });
                        }, 250);
`

after the `else` block.

Comment: What are the other things should I help with?

Comment: i am confused why tableData.data works. shouldnt it be just tableData? since that already contains the data. my property is data so I called it initially as state.data but it didnt work and only state.data.data did work.